# How to link my HTML file to my CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to link my html file to my css file. When I open in chrome browser I only see the html. I have used both absolute file linking and relative and have double and triple checked my file locations. Both the index.html file and style.css file are in the same folder, side-by-side, siblings.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title">My App</h1>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="screenshot"> image</div>

        <div class="description"
            >This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. This is some text on my webpage. </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
*{
    outline: 1px soild red !important;
}
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
    max-width: 460px;
}
.desription {
    max-width: 705px;
}
```

The files are in the same folder, together.

I feel like I've read every question of this nature on here already and no one seems to have had the same issue as me. But if my code is wrong somewhere, maybe I just need a second set of eyes to see it.

I'm somewhat new to this and can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried with `../` ?

Comment: Apart from some formatting imperfections, this should perfectly work. What makes you assume it does not work?

Comment: You won't "see" the CSS - it will just affect the HTML on your page.

Comment: There is a typo in the first style: `outline: 1px soild red`. `soild` should be `solid`. Since this is the most distinct style (actually setting a color), I can imagine it looks like the entire CSS doesn't work. If after this, it still doesn't work, check the developer tools in the browser and see if the CSS is loaded and with what code. `200` means the CSS is loaded okay, `304` means an (old) version is cached. `404` indicates not found.

Comment: Side note: in general don't use `!important`.

Comment: Also notice the difference between `.image` in the CSS and `class="screenshot"` in the HTML.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Nice!Fyi for OP, you can [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) you feel answered your question completely. It helps filter for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you won't "see" the CSS - it will just affect the HTML on your page.

A reason why you aren't seeing the red outline on everything is that you have a typo in your CSS:

```
*{
    outline: 1px soild red !important;
}
```

Should be

```
*{
    outline: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

EDIT: Once you make this change, you may need to do a hard refresh in order to clear the cached version of the CSS - in chrome you can do this by holding ctrl when you fresh, e.g. ctrl + f5.

Comment: `soild` should be `solid`

Comment: Dammit @GolezTrol we keep stepping on each other's toes :D

Comment: Do we? :) Sorry you feel that way. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your `link` is fine. I loaded it up locally.

Your `*` style isn't working because `solid` is misspelled.
`outline: 1px solid red !important;`

Next time, use chrome debugger to make sure style.css is being loaded, then you can know there's something wrong elsewhere (like your css, in this case). If it isn't being loaded correctly, there will be an error (like style.css is not found).

Answer (score 1):

Open Developer tools in your browser and check network tab and look for style.css.